# Laravel: log specific user out

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, logout

I have a role base Laravel app. I have admin role and trying to block a specific user , then immediately log the user out of app. 
so using [`Auth::logout()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)
is not the case as it log myself out not the intended user!

Comment: You'd have to clear out their session somehow. What session storage are you using?

Comment: Default file session driver is used

Comment: Then you'll need to find the user's session file and delete it.

Comment: You may also have to clear out their `remember_me` token in the `users` table if they checked the "remember me" box, so they don't get immediately re-logged-in.

Comment: If you switch to the database driver it stores a `user_id` field so you can simply `delete from sessions where user_id = $id`

Comment: Thanks, but how about file session driver?

Comment: I'll agree with switching to the database driver, there are [some issues noticed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172) when working with file session driver, which might affect your case if the user can still perform `ajax` requests even after being logged out. This same issue above had thrown me for a few days.

Comment: @BenSwinburne  I tested database session driver, but no chance. even if i delete user record from session table , user is still logged in and a new session record will be created as soon as he refresh the page he is on!

Comment: As ceejayoz said, you'll need to delete the remember_me token in the users table too or the cookie on the client will identify the user and create a new session.

Comment: Thanks it does work, but when a user logged out , related session table `user_id` record will be set to null , but the record itself wont be deleted, is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone here suggest you to just delete user session, but I think it's a bad advice, because session can have information which you do not want to delete. Deleting a session just to logout a user is like killing a fly with a bazooka.

More elegant solution is to mark user for logout and check if user is marked on every request. If he's marked, just logout him immediately with simple `Auth::logout()`

You can find code example by clicking the link to my [answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386337/logout-a-user-by-another-useradmin-in-laravel-5-2).

**Update - The test**

Ok, guys, you downvoted me and made me feel like a fool, so I've decided to test things out.

I've switched session driver to a DB.

Then I've made a route with `session->put('mes', 'I\'m here!');` and ran it. After that I've ran action with `echo session->get('mes');`, so I saw the message.

After that I've tried to close browser and open it again. I've logged out with `Auth::logout();` and then logged in. I still saw the message. Session was kept.

Now, when I've deleted session manually with @Ben Swinburne method, the message was gone. Whole session was destroyed.

So, I guess it proves my answer is correct.

Also, look at [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8661#issuecomment-100219843) answer by lukasgeiter.

Comment: Deleting a session is no different then the `Auth::logout()` function, which deletes the session.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to be an elegant way! I think it's not  a good idea to check for specific user id  in EVERY request.there should be better solution.

Comment: @MikeBarwick, can you prove it somehow (link to source code or something)? I don't think logout flushes session.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`, see `logout()` which calls `clearUserDataFromStorage()`. It wipes the data for that session and cleans up cookies and remember tokens.

Comment: @alex, Laravel loads tons of classes, middleware, service providers and services on every request,, It also loads user information any way, so you do not need to hit database just to check if user is marked or not.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Of course it does. `Illuminate/Auth/Guard`. Alex, your answer likely is located in this file. Play around maybe with `Auth::setUser()` or something. I don't know. Can't test right now.

Comment: @MikeBarwick, I don't see a proof in source code. Also, http://laravel.io/forum/02-06-2014-session-destroy?page=1#reply-603

Comment: Search a recent install, for `Illuminate/Auth/Guard`. And I'm not saying kill all user sessions. Just the login one.

Comment: @MikeBarwick, there is no `Illuminate/Auth/Guard` in recent version, it's 5.1's namespace. Found nothing there. Also, from official documentation: *This will clear the authentication information in the user's session: Auth::logout()*, sounds really like *... and doesn't delete other content of the session*

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it does; MikeBarwick is correct. Look at my comment above.

Comment: @BenSwinburne, I'd like to see a proof. I looked inside `logout()` and I don't see anything that flushes session. Also,  discussion at laravel io (link is above)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin The Laravel 5.2 source code for `Auth::logout()` is at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L528. It calls `$this->clearUserDataFromStorage();` which does `$this->session->remove($this->getName());`. By removing the user's session key from the session storage, any data associated with that session is now lost (even if it's still in the data store, it's no longer connected to any browser sessions).

Comment: @ceejayoz, yep I saw this code. It's interesting question, I'll test it tomorrow to see how it works.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, ceejayoz has reiterated my point above accurately and referenced a source. Hopefully that's sufficient? I suspect the problem lies in the fact you've [presumably been looking at Laravel 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895314/#comment-61357868) and the question is tagged 5.2

Comment: Apologies, just looked at 5.1 and it's the same behaviour but it's in `Illuminate\Auth\Guard` instead of `SessionGuard`

Comment: @BenSwinburne, Mike used 5.1 namespace as example, not me.