# Force logout of specific user by user id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.2, and I want to know how to force a user to log out by id. I'm building an admin panel with the option to deactivate a specific user that is currently logged in to the web application. Laravel gives you this option for a current user.

```
Auth::logout()
```

But I don't want to log out the current user, as I am an authenticated user. So I need to force log out of a specific user by its `id`. Just like when we log in a user with a specific id.

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id);
```

Is there something like the following?

```
Auth::logoutUsingId($id);
```

Comment: You can logout and login with you `id`.

Comment: If you want it to be realtime, you can set the deactivation of the users on your side (admin panel) and can use websockets to push a logout event to a specific user (see socket.io). But you need to have a node server to achieve this (logged in users will have to connect to this node server via websockets. Admin panel triggers a `log out user` command to node, then is passed to the user (frontend can force logout in case of a `log out user` event))
If you don't need real time, you can just check a db field every page load and log out if the current logged in user has been deactivated

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin: Cool down man, no one's your enemy here. I read your answer; Even though it doesn't deserve the downvotes but it's not a comprehensive answer regarding the implementation details. It gives the OP a clue to build upon (which is perfectly fine IMO). With around 30k rep, you must know that people here, prefer comprehensive tutorial-like and crystal clear answers over correct, minimal but somehow vague answers. You took a lot of time in the comments to make people understand what you meant, what you could do by adding a better example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Currently, there's no straightforward way to do this; As the [`StatefulGuard`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/StatefulGuard.php) contract and its [`SessionGuard`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php) implementation don't offer a `logoutUsingId()` as they do for [login](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L507).

You need to add a new field to your users table and set it to true when you want a specific user to be logged out. Then use a middleware to check if the current user needs a force logout.

Here's a quick implementation.

###1. Add a new field
Let's add a new field to users table migration class:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // ...
            $table->boolean('logout')->default(false);
            // other fields...
        });
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Make sure you run `php artisan migrate:refresh [--seed]` after changing the migration.

###2. Force logout middleware
Let's create a new [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware):

```php
php artisan make:middleware LogoutUsers
```

Here's the logic to check if a user needs to be kicked out:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class LogoutUsers
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        
        // You might want to create a method on your model to
        // prevent direct access to the `logout` property. Something
        // like `markedForLogout()` maybe.
        if (! empty($user->logout)) {
            // Not for the next time!
            // Maybe a `unmarkForLogout()` method is appropriate here.
            $user->logout = false;
            $user->save();
            
            // Log her out
            Auth::logout();
            
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

###3. Register the middleware in HTTP kernel
Open up the [`app/Http/Kernel.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/Kernel.php#L25) and add your middleware's FQN:

```php
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array<string, class-string|string>
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'ForceJsonResponse' =>\App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
    'localize'                => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
    'localizationRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
    'localeSessionRedirect'   => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
    'localeCookieRedirect'    => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleCookieRedirect::class,
    'localeViewPath'          => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class,
    'LogoutUsers' => \App\Http\Middleware\LogoutUsers::class// <= Here,
```

It's untested code, but it should give you the idea. It'd be a good practice to add a couple of API methods to your `User` model to accompany with this functionality:

- `markedForLogout()` : Checks user's `logout` flag.
- `markForLogout()` : Sets user's `logout` flag to `true`.
- `unmarkForLogout()` : Sets user's `logout` flag to `false`.

Then on the administration side (I suppose it's your case), you just need to call `markForLogout()` on the specific user model to kick him out on the next request. Or you can utilize the query builder to set the flag, if the model object is not available:

```php
User::where('id', $userId)
    ->update(['logout' => true]);
```

It can be a `markForLogoutById($id)` method.

**Related discussions**
[[Proposal] Log out users by ID](https://github.com/laravel/internals/issues/360)
[Multiple statements when logged users are deleted](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3577)

Comment: A good idea, but this implementation doesn't provide the ability to log out several browser sessions, only a first browser that requests the site.

Answer (score 14):

### Use the setUser to find a soluion

- get current user

  ```
     $user = Auth::user();
  ```
- logout user you want to, by id

  ```
     $userToLogout = User::find(5);
     Auth::setUser($userToLogout);
     Auth::logout();
  ```
- set again current user

  ```
     Auth::setUser($user);
  ```

Comment: you can simply Auth::logout(); for logout

Comment: Dear @KashifSaleem! Simply Auth::logout(); will log out the current user, here our concern is to logout a user other then the current user.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to override App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate **handle** function with custom check

```
if ($this->auth->user()->deleted_at) {
    $this->auth->logout();
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The setup and below code I use it to logout a user and also lock his account(optional)using checklist, I did it through Ajax Request:

-In config/session.php, change to:

'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

-run php artisan session:table
-run php artisan migrate //a session table is created.

-in .env file: change   SESSION_DRIVER=file to SESSION_DRIVER=database

Now the coding part:
-In controller:

```
    function ajaxCheckList(Request $request)
    {
//                \Log::info($request);
        $user = \App\Models\User::findOrFail($request['user_id']);
        $locked = 0;
        if ($user->locked == 1) {
            $user->locked = 0;
            $locked = 0;
        } else {
            $user->locked = 1;
            $locked = 1;
            DB::table('sessions')
                ->where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
                ->delete();
        }
        $user->update(['locked' => $locked]);
    }
```