# delete user session by keeping SESSION_DRIVER=file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

We can easily delete other users session if `SESSION_DRIVER=database` and by using database query to delete user.

Now, I am trying to use session in file `SESSION_DRIVER=file` because I have complex object in Session. So, it may cause performance issue.

Is there any way to delete user session by admin by keeping `SESSION_DRIVER=file`?

I am searching to get file name of User session stored in `storage\framework\sessions`

**Edit - 1**

Framework is making unique file name and storing data in that file and keeping it in storage\framework\sessions. How is framework getting to know about which user has which file name?

Comment: Are you testing locally? And are you looking for the session file for admin? why don't you use `session()->forget('key')`

Comment: Lets say we both are part of an application. We both are logged in. How can you log me out where SESSION_DRIVER=file?

Comment: [Laravel - force logout of specific user by user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440352/laravel-force-logout-of-specific-user-by-user-id)

Comment: Framework is making unique file name and storing data in that file and keeping it in storage\framework\sessions. How is framework getting to know about which user has which file name?