# logout the admin user after delete this admin (laravel 8 )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to delete the admin user by just make him password and email as empty Because I need him rest Information in the database
so when i need to delete him I want to change password and email as empty and the same time I want to log him out of the system immediately

every thing works fine but without log him out

**here is delete function**

```
 public function DeleteAdminRole($id){
    
            $adminimg = Admin::findOrFail($id);
            $img = $adminimg->profile_photo_path;
            if($img){
            unlink($img);
            
        }
         Auth::logout($adminimg);
            Admin::findOrFail($id)->update([
                'type' =>3,
                'email'=>"",
                'password'=>"",
    
            ]);
    
             $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Admin User Deleted Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'info'
            );
    
            return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
    
        } // end method
```

Comment: alternatively you can use `softDeletes` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-softDeletes

Comment: You can change the auth middleware to check if the user still has a password, and log him out when he does not. That way the user will be logged out at the next action. for a live logout, javascript will be needed I think. A better way than to remove the password is to use a bool col in the database 'locked' for example, so if you need to restore the user for some reason, the username/pass is not lost.

Comment: I do agree with you but the client wants that just want to make empty password and email and log out this admin

Comment: @ALAAELDIN changing the middleware as I commented, will do the trick, the rest of the comment was just a tip :-)

Comment: i am in AdminRedirectIfAuthenticated  Middleware

I have edit this function as u told me but doesn't work

public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() & Admin::where('type',2) ) {
                return redirect($guard.'/dashboard');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

Comment: That is the middleware to redirect on login. does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440352/force-logout-of-specific-user-by-user-id-in-laravel . the accepted answer uses a custom middleware, thats not a bad idea.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work with me